# Android AdMob Example for someone doing development in notepad, command line and ant

Tags: ant, admob

Does anyone know of a complete example corresponding to https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en_US but for someone who is doing development in notepad and using command line and ant for build? I am forced to use command line since android studio just doesn't work for me. it locks up and is just stuck with 100% CPU usage.

Comment: Notepad? Really?! If Android Studio does not work for you then try Eclipse with the adt plugin: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Comment: i don't like eclipse either. both tools just don't work for me. i only need to write minimal android to integrate ads into my app. rest of my app is html based and doesn't require any java.